# PHP prepared statement error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I've spent the whole day trying to figure out this problem with no luck. I've seen some questions where a constant was being used directly as an argument. All of my arguments are variables though. Am I missing something really obvious?

```
$one = 1;
$two = 2;
$three = 3;

if (  !($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO test3 (one, two, three) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'))  ) {
  echo "Prepare failed (".$stmt->errno.") ".$stmt->error."\n";
  $stmt->close();
  exit();
}

if (  !($stmt->bind_param('iii',$one,$two,$three))  ) {
  echo "Failed to bind (".$stmt->errno.") ".$stmt->error;
  $stmt->close();
  exit();
}

if (  !($stmt->execute)  ) {
  echo "Execute failed (". $stmt->errno.") ". $stmt->error."\n";
  $stmt->close();
  exit();
}
```

EDIT: I was actually using `bind_param` but forgot to change it back after experimenting with different things. The code was copied and pasted as it was. After changing bind_value back to bind_param I still get the same error.

EDIT 2: I feel stupid, I saved my php file with a new name so I could simplify the code, but I forgot to change the url of the POST method to reflect that change. So the error I'm now getting is: `Undefined property: mysqli_stmt::$execute` and the corresponding output in the mysql log:

```
42 Connect     test@localhost on testdb
42 Prepare     [1] INSERT INTO test3 (one, two, three) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
42 Quit
```

Comment: You are certain this is the offending code? Is this the real code?

Comment: Could you post full error message with line number ?

Comment: According to [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php), there is no such function as `mysqli_stmt::bind_value`?

Comment: @Zaffy: Thanks, I noticed the line number exceeded the number of lines in my file, and hence I realized it was accessing a different file to the one I was working with.

Comment: Read the error message, and look up the difference between *property* and *method*. `mysqli_stmt::execute` is a method, you need to add `()` after it: `if(!$stmt->execute()) `.

Comment: Thankyou! I know the difference, but my problem was I wasn't getting any error messages. It was showing `Execute failed(0)` and that was it.

Comment: @DCoder: Now I have a clear head after some sleep, you are absolutely right. I don't know why the `Undefined property` in the message didn't register with me. It is pretty obvious now. Maybe it's because I saw my own error message "Failed to execute" before looking at the log and forming an assumption that the execute method had actually run.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysqli you must use bind_param instead of bind_value:

```
if (  !($stmt->bind_param('iii',$one,$two,$three))  ) {
  echo "Failed to bind (".$stmt->errno.") ".$stmt->error;
  $stmt->close();
  exit();
}
```

BindValue is only for the PDO Class.

Comment: Sorry, it was originally bind_param but I tried bind_value and forgot to change it back.

Answer (score 0):

In your code below I added one line of code. I had the same problem and checking the documentation again this fixed my problem.

```
$one = 1;
$two = 2;
$three = 3;

// This fixed my problem 
$stmt =  $mysqli->stmt_init();

if (  !($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO test3 (one, two, three) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'))  ) {
  echo "Prepare failed (".$stmt->errno.") ".$stmt->error."\n";
  $stmt->close();
  exit();
}

if (  !($stmt->bind_param('iii',$one,$two,$three))  ) {
  echo "Failed to bind (".$stmt->errno.") ".$stmt->error;
  $stmt->close();
  exit();
}

if (  !($stmt->execute)  ) {
  echo "Execute failed (". $stmt->errno.") ". $stmt->error."\n";
  $stmt->close();
  exit();
}
```

Check out the docs here http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.stmt-init.php
You will also see it being used in there [mysqli::prepare page](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php)

Answer (score 0):

You typed it incorrectly: `$stmt->execute`
`execute` is not a property, it's a method.

There's no property called `execute`, this is why the log saying `undefined property`

Your code should look like:

```
if (  !($stmt->execute())  ) {
  echo "Execute failed (". $stmt->errno.") ". $stmt->error."\n";
  $stmt->close();
  exit();
}
```

Hope this will help